# What's the difference between static and templates folder under resources in a springboot & thymeleaf project?

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to thymeleaf and springboot.

I create a springboot project with thymeleaf in IntelliJ IDEA with "New Project"->"Spring Initalizr".

Then I get a project whose structure looks like below.

```
demo
  |+-src/main
  |    +-java
  |    +-resources
  |         static
  |         templates
  |         application.properties
  |-pom.xml
```

The question is what should I put in static and templates under resources? What's the difference between them?

I guess the .html files that have thymeleaf attributes should be put in templates. How about static html, css and js?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`templates` folder is a place where you put all the thymeleaf templates. It is a default directory (by default spring will look inside for any templates).

`static` folder is used for serving web static content, all the css, js, html etc. (also default folder search by spring) 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: Unfortunately IntelliJ does not seem to provide code completion for paths / files in the static folder for Thymeleaf templates when using something like `th:src="@{/images/logos/mylogo.png}"`.

It will work fine when you run the app, but no code completion as you would have for a standard HTML `src=` tag when working on the template.

Comment: @SiriusBits You can using the web descriptor in artifacts https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/web-application-static-content.html I added both as "/" and IntelliJ was able to give me code completion.

Answer (score 0):

These folders are a way of organizing your files. These `static` and `templates` folders have special meaning in a case that it know has become common understanding for organizing your frontend files such as `css`, `js`, `html` etc among developers. In my understanding we should place files like `css`, `js`, `images` that supports your web pages which are not going to change through out your application at runtime. For eg: your design is not going to change which is done in your `css` file. In `templates` we should place `html` files. If you add both html and other files together, it becomes hard to organize your files.

Comment: Where should I place the html files that have no thymeleaf attributes? They don't change at runtime.

Comment: still add those in `templates` folder, which includes the structure and layout of your web application.

Comment: where  should I  put an  angular app  with  index.html ?  In   /static /public or /templates ?