# template engines vs static resources

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, template-engine

In static resources I can have html files with their `css` and `javascript` files so i can have a fully dynamic site.

what are the benefits of using over template engines over static resources(like `thymeleaf`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between static and templates folder under resources in a springboot & thymeleaf project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780531/whats-the-difference-between-static-and-templates-folder-under-resources-in-a-s)

Comment: I know where to put templates files and static files. so it is not a duplicate question. @ChrisMaggiulli
my question is what are the benefits of using template engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [Thymeleaf templates](https://www.thymeleaf.org) can be static resources

> HTML templates written in Thymeleaf still look and work like HTML

Template engines can display **dynamic** content in semmingly static resources.

See detailed [example](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-thymeleaf/) on how to display `name` using thymeleaf and Spring

> ```
>   <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
> ```

Comment: I can create some the same with a `jquery` code retrieving string `name` from a url in my backend. 
@user7294900

Comment: @kingGarfield -- Yes, you can.  You do the same things with javascript and web services as you can with a template engine.  They're different ways of solving the same problem.  A template engine combines the front and backend together.  You are basically generating a "dynamic" static resources each time you access the server.